# How to format properly when converting from string to bytes

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to keep the formatting when converting from a string to bytes.

For example:

```
string = "Hello \n my \n name \n is \n foo"

bites = bytes(string, 'utf-8')
```

And I would like the bites variable to format in the same way the string does where there is a new line after every \n

Comment: What do you mean by that? `\n` is newline, there's no newline after it.

Comment: By \n I mean new line. When I print the variable bites I would like the new line to also happen like how it does when I print string

Comment: Byte strings aren't text, so `print(bites)` won't format it as text.

Comment: Why are you converting it to a byte string if you want it to be formatted like a regular string?

Comment: Do you want the `\n` *and* a newline to be displayed? That's more than just formatting; that requires a separately built string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default method `__str__` method of `bytes` is implemented in the way so that 0x0A (the newline character is encoded by 0x0A in ASCII) are printed as `\n`.

If you want it to print as a newline character, you can implement your own `bytes` class this way:

```py
class MyBytes(bytes):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.decode()
string = "Hello \n my \n name \n is \n foo"
bites = MyBytes(string, 'utf-8')
```

Then if you `print(bites)`; it gives you the new line.

Comment: To emphasize the point, I wouldn't refer to the byte `0x0a` as a newline (or more properly, a linefeed character). A linefeed refers to a particular semantic notion defined by the ASCII encoding, something not implied by a raw `bytes` value.

Comment: @chepner I agree with you, a particular byte value 0x0a out of context, shouldn't be called newline character. But in the context of OP, I think it is easier to understand what I mean by calling it 'newline character'.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a "raw string" prefixed by `r`

```py
>>> print(r"my raw\nstring")
my raw\nstring
>>> print("my raw\nstring")
my raw
string
```

Answer (score 0):

A `bytes` object is different from a `str` object.

The `print` method will behave different depending in the object passed to it, since it calls the `__str__` method from the object. So, for a `bytes` object it prints the string without transforming special characters, like newlines to actual newlines.

```
>>> print(bites)
b'Hello \n my \n name \n is \n foo'
>>> a = bites.__str__()
>>> a  # this is a string with newlines scaped
"b'Hello \\n my \\n name \\n is \\n foo'"
>>> isinstance(a, str)
True
>>> isinstance(bites, bytes)
True
```

If you want to print bytes with newlines the best alternative would be to transform it to a string

```
>>> a = bites.decode('utf-8')
>>> isinstance(a, str)
True
>>> a
'Hello \n my \n name \n is \n foo'
>>> print(a)
Hello
 my
 name
 is
 foo
```